# python's accumulate equivalent in clojure

Tags: python, clojure

I would like an equivalent of Python's [itertools.accumulate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=accumulate#itertools.accumulate) in Clojure.

If you aren't familiar, it's basically `reduce()`, but it stores the output of each call to the reducing function.

I can't seem to find a 1:1 equivalent in the built-in clojure functions. My closest working approximation is

```clj
(defn accumulate
  "Like `reduce` but stores result of every step."
  ([f coll]
   (accumulate f (first coll) (rest coll)))

  ([f val coll]
   (loop [result [val]
          current-val val
          next-val (first coll)
          coll (rest coll)]
     (if (empty? coll)
       (conj result (f current-val next-val))
       (let [new-val (f current-val next-val)]
         (recur (conj result new-val)
                new-val
                (first coll)
                (rest coll)))))))
```

Is there an already existing function that does this?

If not, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reductions ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Guess I just needed to look harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zehnpaard said, you are looking for `reductions`. But your custom function could also be greatly simplified:

```clj
(defn accumulate [f coll] 
    (reduce #(conj %1 (f (last %1) %2)) [(first coll)] (rest coll)))
```